# How do You Split String into Words and Special Characters in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to split a string into words `[a-zA-Z]` and any special character that it may contain except `@` and `#` symbols

`message = "I am to be @split, into #words, And any other thing that is not word, mostly special character(.,>)"`

**Expected Result:**

`['I', 'am', 'to', 'be', '@split', ',', 'into', '#words', ',', 'And', 'any', 'other', 'thing', 'that', 'is', 'not', 'word', ',', 'mostly', 'special', 'character', '(', '.', ',', '>', ')']`

How can I achieve this in Python?

Comment: So, how exactly do you define "words" and "special characters"?

Comment: @JoelCornett: I mean ASCII special characters, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_characters

Comment: Shouldn't `'#words,'` be `'#word',','`?

Comment: @JoelCornett: Do you know about exceptions? Don't you understand my question?

Comment: @Yax: I'm sorry. I was on my phone and did not see the first sentence in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
re.findall(r"[A-Za-z@#]+|\S", message)
```

The pattern matches any sequence of word characters (here, defined as letters plus `@` and `#`), or any single non-whitespace character.

Comment: This did it but I tried `' '.join(message)` and my special character are spaced from their original place.

Comment: @Yax: Well, yes. The question as you asked it says to throw away all of the spaces, so there's no way to tell how things were spaced out before. If you simply insert a space between every list item in the result, you'll get a bunch of extras.

Comment: Isn't there a way I can around this? I don't go about asking another question for this.

Comment: @Yax: I'm not sure what the point is. If you split the words and symbols preserving spaces somehow, then rejoin them, you'll get the original string.

Comment: I am fetching `#hashtags and @mentions` in a post and I want to replace them with HTML `<a hrfe='#hashtag'>#hashtag</a>` so they can become clickable when rendered in HTML page.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to split every word and symbol, only the ones that start with `@` and `#`. Try: `re.sub(r"[@#]\w+", lambda m: '<a href="{0}">{0}</a>'.format(m.group()), message)`. And read about the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/223254), so you can ask better questions in the future!

Comment: This gives error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Comment: Yep, I posted my code too quickly, but fixed it after posting. Try the version in the edited comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63708/discussion-between-yax-and-blckknght).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a character class to specify all of the characters you *don't* want for the split.  `[^\w@#]` -- this means every character except letters/numbers/underscore/@/#

Then you can capture the special characters as well using capturing parentheses in `re.split`.

```
filter(None, re.split(r'\s|([^\w@#])', message))
```

The `filter` is done to remove empty strings from splitting between special characters.  The `\s|` part is so that spaces are not captured.

Comment: This also did it but I tried `' '.join(message)` and my special character are spaced from their original place.